# C++ Constructor for Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion, explicit-constructor

I have these codes:

```
class Type2 {
public:
  Type2(const Type1 & type);
  Type2(int);
const Type2 & operator=(const Type2 & type2);
//....
};

...
  Type1 t1(13);
  Type2 t2(4);

  t2=t1;
```

As I understood, the 1-argument constructors of Type2 each without an *explicit* keyword should mean any Type1 objects or int values can be implicitly conveted to Type2 objects.

But in the last line *t2=t1;*, MS Visual Studio gives me this compile error:

> ....error C2679: binary '=' : no operator
>   found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'Type1' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)....

Seems like MS Visual Studio insisting *t2=t1;* must match an assignment operator with lhs=Type2 and rhs=Type1.  Why can't it implicitly cast rhs to t2 and then do the copying with the Type2=Type2 operator?

Comment: This code compiles fine for me in VS2010.

Comment: I know why. Because my Type1 has a conversion operator: class Type1 { operator Type2() };

Comment: Can I close a question that I have found the answer myself?

Comment: @JavaMan: you can (and should) answer your own question.

Comment: @JavaMan: Its even appropriate to mark your own answer as accepted answer to let the community know that this issue is now resolved.

Comment: @JavaMan: I still think you are misunderstanding or Visual Studio 2010 is in error. In the example you gave in your question, the conversion operator is missing a `const`, which removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.  Because my Type1 got a conversion operator

```
    class Type1 {
    public:
        Type1 (int );
        operator  Type2() ;//casting to Type2

    ....
    };
```

This is something called **"dual-direction implicit conversion"**

Comment: Interesting.  This compiles fine in GCC.

Comment: Yes, even VS2010 does compile sometimes. But I have to figure out exactly when. This is the standard ambiguous situation that compiler cannot tell which conversion should be used. IMHO, they should produce compile time error.

Comment: If Type2 got an assignment operator for Type2=Type1, VS2010 does compile. BTW, the reason I am testing all these is that I want to figure out if the compilers can identify these ambiguous situations (as pointed out by my C++ book)

Comment: @VJo: The OP's code snippet(s) combined, plus dummy function bodies.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

using ::std::cerr;

class Barney;

class Fred {
 public:
   Fred() { }
   Fred(const Barney &b) { cerr << "Using conversion constructor.\n"; }
};

class Barney {
 public:
   Barney() { }
   operator Fred() const { cerr << "Using conversion operator.\n"; return Fred(); }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   const Barney b;
   Fred f;
   f = b;
   return 0;
}
```

generates this error in gcc 4.6:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall fred.cpp -o a.out
fred.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
fred.cpp:23:8: error: conversion from ‘const Barney’ to ‘const Fred’ is ambiguous
fred.cpp:21:17: note: candidates are:
fred.cpp:16:4: note: Barney::operator Fred() const
fred.cpp:10:4: note: Fred::Fred(const Barney&)
fred.cpp:7:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Fred& Fred::operator=(const Fred&)’

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Jun 19 04:13:53
```

Now, if I remove the `const` after `operator Fred()`, it then compiles, and uses the conversion constructor. If I also remove the `const` from the declaration of `b` in `main`, it then prefers the conversion operator.

This all fits the overload resolution rules. And gcc generates the appropriate ambiguity error when it can't pick between the conversion operator and the conversion contructor.

I notice that in the examples you gave, the conversion operator is missing a `const`. This means that there will never be a case in which using the conversion operator or the converting constructor is ambiguous.